# Probability question: $P(A\mid B) > P(B)$ or $<P(A)$ or $> P(A)$

Tags: probability

> Let A and B be two events with positive probability each, defined on
>   the same sample space. Find the correct answer:
>
> a) $P(A\mid B) > P(A)$ always
>
> (b) $P(A\mid B) < P(A)$ always
>
> (c) $P(A\mid B) > P(B)$ always
>
> (d) None of the above

If $P(A\cap B)=0$ then $P(A\mid B$ is always less than $P(A)$ and $P(B)$

If $P(A\cap B)\neq0$ then$:$  it can be anything, we can't come to any specific solution.

So, the answer is (d).

Is this correct? and is there a way in which i can be 100% sure about my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the event that tossing coin $1$ gives us head, the probability of doing so is $0.25$.

Let  $B$ be another independent coin toss that gives us head, the probability of achieving that is $0.75$.

Hence $P(A|B)=P(A)<P(B)$ which show that (a),(b), (c) do not hold all the time.